# Redimensionamento da janela e eventos mouseover e mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tive hoje o seguinte problema, criei uma função que verifica o tamanho da janela do browser e se ele for maior que `1300`, o li recebe duas classe e o link (`<a>`) dentro dele recebe um evento de `mouseover` e `mouseout`.

Senão, ele só adiciona três classes ao `li`. Chamo essa função no carregamento da página e na função resize do `window` para que, quando for redimensionado, também ele verifique o tamanho da janela.

Tudo lindo e tal, porém acontece o problema, quando redimensiono, ele continua com os eventos do `li`, mesmo a janela recebendo um novo `width`. Mas quando dou refresh com a página menor que o valor de `1300`, ele não recebe o evento de `mouseover` e `mouseout`.

Alguém tem ideia do motivo disso acontecer?

Segue o codigo:

```
var areaRestrita = function(larguraJanela) {

    if(larguraJanela > 1300) {

        $('#menu-item-7436').addClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita-default area-restrita-default')
        .removeClass('area-restrita');

        $('#menu-item-7436>a').mouseover(function(v){

            $('#menu-item-7436')
            .removeClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita-default area-restrita-default')
            .addClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita area-restrita');
        });

        $('#menu-item-7436>a').mouseout(function(v){

            $('#menu-item-7436')
            .removeClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita area-restrita')
            .addClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita-default area-restrita-default');

        });

    } else {

        $('#menu-item-7436').addClass('area-restrita')
        .removeClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita barra-lateral-area-restrita-default area-restrita-default')
    }

}

areaRestrita($(window).width());

$(window).resize(function(){

    areaRestrita($(window).width());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que falta desligar os eventos de `mouseover` e `mouseout` quando a janela fica mais pequena, caso contrário eles continuam lá.

Isso é feito através da função `unbind` do JQuery.

No seu código entraria na parte do `else` e ficaria assim:

```
else {

    $('#menu-item-7436').addClass('area-restrita')
    .removeClass('barra-lateral-area-restrita barra-lateral-area-restrita-default area-restrita-default');

    $('#menu-item-7436>a').unbind("mouseover"); //desligar o hover in
    $('#menu-item-7436>a').unbind("mouseout"); //desligar o hover out
}
```

Comment: Po deu certo, muito obrigado!!!!